# Prevent setTimeout() from firing every time when hiding notification

Tags: javascript, vue.js, settimeout, eventemitter

I have a simple popup notification component that should hide after 4 seconds (opacity:0). Problem is that I want a notification to stay if I fire an event that makes a notification appear and then later disappear after 4 seconds. Now everything works as it should but setTimeout() stacks on each other, I want only last setTimeout() to fire, how do I achieve that?

So basically I want my notification to stay visible as long as a button that is emitting an event is being clicked and only last time that is clicked, setTimeout() should fire.

Here is my problematic code:

```
showNotification(v){
        this.popupProduct = v;
        this.showPopup = true;
        setTimeout(()=>{
            console.log(this.showPopup)  
        this.showPopup = false;

        },4000)
    },
```

Showing of notification is being dictated by `this.showPopup` which is stored inside the Vue data object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to store the id of the timeout and clear it at the beginning of the function:

```
showNotification(v) {
    if (this.timeoutId) {
      clearTimeout(this.timeoutId)
      this.timeoutId = undefined
    }
    this.popupProduct = v;
    this.showPopup = true;
    this.timeoutId = setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log(this.showPopup)  
    this.showPopup = false;

    },4000)
},
```